# InDesign, characters extending outside text box

Tags: adobe-indesign, margin

I'm a beginner at using InDesign and I'm currently designing a book that is meant to be read on a phone.
In order for the book to look good on the phone I need to have zero margins on the top and bottom since I don't want to have any indication of where a page begins and ends.

The problem is that this starts to happen to some characters:
[image: Problem 1]

I would like InDesign to move the text to the next page if this occurs. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don’t think you can, unfortunately. Descenders are simply not counted in InDesign; only the baseline matters. You can set the _top_ of a frame to be based on leading/x-height/cap height, but I don’t think there’s a way to set the _bottom_ to the descender height (lowth?) rather than the baseline.

Answer (score 2):

Add spacing to the bottom to this particular text frame that suits your fonts descenders + additional space that you want.

[image: Text frame options]